# How to restrict only 1 row to get updated in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I am trying to convert the below Oracle sql to postgres sql:

```
Update Table_name set flag='U' WHERE id= 1 and ROWNUM < 2.
```

if the data in the table is some thing like

[image]

Then the query should update only one record as Unique like flag='U'.. and other records should not be effected.

[image]

Note:There is no unique key nor primary key on the table. I don't have access rights to create a constraint.

Since ROWNUM is not available in postgres, I am not able to do convert this query into postgres.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The standard `rownumber()` function is available though. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html

Comment: How come rownumber() will restrict the no of records that are getting updated. It provides a sequence for the result and that can be captured in a column, but it cannot restrict the no of records that are getting effected on the table. Please enlighten me with an example if I am thinking in wrong direction. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pseudo column [CTID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/ddl-system-columns.html) here -

```
Update Table_name
   SET flag='U'
 WHERE CTID IN (SELECT CTID FROM Table_name WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: The above works, but OP needs to take caution. Since the current value of the flag is not specified and you are not sorting (data provided does not permit determining a unique sort sequence anyway) you **cannot** know /specify in advance which row will get updated. Postgres will happy update  *flag=U* to *flag=U' as many times as you want, or randomly pick another one t update.

Comment: you hit the bull's-eye. This is exactly what I need. Thankyou so much

Comment: Since CTID is the physical location of the row version within its table. I hope there will be no challenges when we move it to cloud. Please suggest if I have to take any preliminary checks. For this scenario I am not bothered about which row will be updated, I just need one roe to be updated.